# i try to pass data from controller to partial view in viewdata but it didn't work correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views, viewdata

I'm trying to pass data from my controller to a partial view using ViewData but it's not working correctly.

#### code in controller

```
public PartialViewResult PartFace()
    {

        string message = "You are not connected to Facebook";
        string name = "";
        string appid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppID"];
        FacebookConnect fbConnect = new FacebookConnect();
        if (fbConnect.IsConnected)
        {
            message = "You are connected to Facebook";
            string token = fbConnect.AccessToken;
            token = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token);
            Facebook.FacebookAPI api = new Facebook.FacebookAPI(token);
            JSONObject me = api.Get("/" + fbConnect.UserID);
        }
        ViewData["Message"] = message;
        ViewData["AppID"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppID"];
        ViewData["Name"] = name;
        return PartialView();
    }
```

#### code in partial view

```
<h2><%: ViewData["AppID"]%></h2>
<% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)ViewData["Name"])) { %>
<h2>Hello, <%: (string)ViewData["Name"]%> </h2>
<% } %>
<p>
    <fb:profile-pic uid="loggedinuser" facebook-logo="true" linked="false"></fb:profile-pic>
    <fb:login-button autologoutlink='true' onlogin='window.location.reload()' perms='read_stream,publish_stream,read_friendlists,user_activities'></fb:login-button>
</p>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: '<%= ViewData["AppID"] %>', status: true, cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>
```

#### code to call this partial in master page

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/PartFace.ascx"); %>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what aspect of this is not working correctly? What output are you getting?

Comment: first i want to know how to pass data from controller to partialview

Comment: You can return a View and call a PartialView within this view. From Controller to PartialView makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ViewModel:

```
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int AppId { get; set; }
        // ...
    }
```

Pass it to you view like this

```
return View(new ViewModel() { Message = "Works" });
```

then you can access this in you view by setting

```
@model ViewModel;

@Model.Message
```

if you want to pass informations to a partial view you can do this (in your view)

```
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/PartFace.ascx", Model)
```

if you want to pass your model or

```
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/PartFace.ascx", Model.AppId)
```

if you want the appid getting passed to your partial.

hope this helps

Comment: +1: Good advice, but could you change the answer to work in the ASP.NET View Engine (not Razor)?

Comment: problem in passing data from "controller" to "partialview"

Comment: ahh ok, ive changed my answer. hope thats it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You render the partial view directly. In order to get the data from the controller you should call `RenderAction` like this:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("PartFace"); %>
```

Note that if the call is from a view rendered by a different controller than the one containing the `PartFace` action you should also specify the corresponding controller:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("PartFace", "[controller]"); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, this solution did work for me.

1. Created ViewDataDictionary collection
2. assigned the collection to viewData property of a partial before return.

   ```
   public PartialViewResult PartFace() {

   string message = "You are not connected to Facebook";
   string name = "";
   string appid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppID"];
   FacebookConnect fbConnect = new FacebookConnect();
   if (fbConnect.IsConnected)
   {
       message = "You are connected to Facebook";
       string token = fbConnect.AccessToken;
       token = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token);
       Facebook.FacebookAPI api = new Facebook.FacebookAPI(token);
       JSONObject me = api.Get("/" + fbConnect.UserID);
   }

   ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
   viewData.Add("Message", message);
   viewData.Add("AppID",  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppID"]);
   viewData.Add("Name",  name);

   var partialView = PartialView();
   partialView.ViewData = viewData;

   return partialView;
   }
   ```